# "Insufficent allowance"

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging

Looking for assistance on what I'm doing wrong.

I have a simple `ERC20` contract I built from scratch for practice interacting with a simple `vendor` contract that allows someone to buy and sell tokens.  My issue is with the *sell logic*.

1. Deploy both contracts `foWERC20.sol` and `Vendor.sol`
2. Send tokens (*500* or more) from the minter account to the `vender.sol` contract
3. Purchased tokens from `Vender.sol` in quantities of 500 with an address that has no tokens
4. Attempts to sell tokens (*500* at a time) back to `Vendor.sol` in exchange for ether

**Problem:**

When `sellToken()` is called from `Vendor.sol` on line *39*, it triggers 2 external contracts inside of `foWERC20.sol` called `approve()` and than `transferFrom()`.Inside of `approve()`,  This function is supposed to set *x* amount of tokens another address has the rights of moving out of the callers wallet.

Inside of `transferFrom` is where the flag happens.
line *100* `require()` does not pass and triggers the warning.
`require(approvedAmount >= _value, "Insufficent allowance");`

So it seems the approved amount is not being set

**Vendor.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./FoWERC20.sol";

//@Dev this contract allows buying and selling of the FOW token along with the withdrawl
//of ETH paid in exchange for FOW


contract Vendor is Ownership {
    
    address vendorOwner;

    FoWERC20 fowERC20; // Custom FOW ERC20 Contract address

    event BuyTokenEvent(address indexed purchasedBy, address indexed purchasedFrom, uint256 ethValue);
    event SellTokenEvent(address indexed soldBy, address indexed soldTo, uint256 ethValue);
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    constructor(address _fowERC20){
        vendorOwner = msg.sender;
        fowERC20 = FoWERC20(_fowERC20);
        
    }

    function buyToken() external payable returns(bool success){
        //tokens per 1 ether
        uint256 tokensPerEther = 500;
        //check if contract caller has enough funds
        require(msg.value >= 1 ether, "Not enough funds");
        //check if vender contract has enough tokens to sell
        require(fowERC20.balanceOf(address(this)) >= tokensPerEther, "Not enough Tokens");
        //create the transfer of tokens in exchange for ether 
        (bool _success) = fowERC20.transfer(msg.sender, (msg.value / 1 ether) * tokensPerEther);      
        emit BuyTokenEvent(msg.sender, address(this), msg.value);
        return _success;
    }

    function sellToken(uint256 howManyTokens) external payable returns(bool){
        //make selling sell in units of 500 tokens
        require(howManyTokens % 500 == 0, "Must sell in quantities of 500");
        //check if contract has a min amount of eth to trade for sale of tokens 
        require(address(this).balance >= 1.1 ether, "Contract balance has less than 1.1 ether");
        //proved address and amount allowed to be extracted from sellers address
        fowERC20.approve(address(this), howManyTokens);
        //transfer tokens from caller(seller) to contract 
        fowERC20.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), howManyTokens);
        //caller(seller) pays contract in ether
        (bool success,) = msg.sender.call{value: (howManyTokens * 1e18 )}("");
        emit SellTokenEvent(msg.sender, address(this), msg.value);
        return success;
    }

}
```

**foWERC20.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

abstract contract ERC20{
    function name() external virtual returns (string memory);
    function symbol() external virtual  returns (string memory);
    function decimals() external virtual  returns (uint8);
    function totalSupply() external virtual  returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address _owner) external virtual view returns (uint256 balance);
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) external virtual returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) external virtual returns (bool success);
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) external virtual returns (bool success);
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) external virtual view returns (uint256 remaining);

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);


    }

    contract Ownership{

        address public contractOwner;
        address public newContractOwner;

        event changeOfOwnershipEvent(address indexed changeFrom, address indexed changeTo);

        constructor(){
            contractOwner = msg.sender;
        }

        function changeOwnership(address _newContractOwner) external returns(bool success){
            require(msg.sender == contractOwner, "Not contract owner");
            newContractOwner = _newContractOwner;
            emit changeOfOwnershipEvent(msg.sender, newContractOwner);
            return true;
        }

        function approveOwnershipChange() external returns(bool success){
            require(msg.sender == newContractOwner, "Not the new contract owner");
            contractOwner = newContractOwner;
            newContractOwner = address(0);
            return true;
        }
    }


    contract FoWERC20 is ERC20, Ownership{

        string _name;
        string _symbol;
        uint8 _decimals;
        uint256 _totalSupply;
        address public _minter;
        
        mapping(address => uint256) public _balance;
        mapping(address => mapping( address => uint256)) public _allowance; 

        constructor(string memory name_, 
                    string memory symbol_,
                    uint8 decimals_,
                    uint256 totalSupply_,
                    address minter_){

            _name = name_;
            _symbol = symbol_;
            _decimals = decimals_;
            _totalSupply = totalSupply_;
            _minter = minter_;           
            _balance[minter_] = totalSupply_;

        }


        function name() public override view returns (string memory){
            return _name;
        }

        function symbol() public override view returns (string memory){
            return _symbol;

        }
        function decimals() public override view returns (uint8){
            return _decimals;
        }

        function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint256){
            return _totalSupply;
        } 

        function balanceOf(address _owner) external override view returns (uint256 balance){
            return _balance[_owner];
        }

        function ethBalance(address _address) external view returns(uint){
            return _address.balance;
        }

        function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) external override returns (bool success){
            require(_balance[msg.sender] >= _value, "Transfer(): Insufficent Funds");
            _balance[msg.sender] -= _value;
            _balance[_to] += _value;
            emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
            return true;
        }

        function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) external override returns (bool success){
        //grabs the approved amount spender is allowed to control from mapping _allowance
        uint256 approvedAmount = _allowance[_from][_to];
        //checks approvedAmount is greater or equal to the value being asked to be removed
        require(approvedAmount >= _value, "Insufficent allowance");
        //updateds allowance to stop reentry exploit
        _allowance[_from][_to] -= _value;
        _balance[_from] -= _value;
        _balance[_to] += _value;
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
        function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) external override returns (bool success){
            require(_balance[msg.sender] >= _value, "Insufficent Funds");
            _allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
            emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
            return true;

        }
        function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) external override view returns (uint256 remaining){
            return _allowance[_owner][_spender];
        }

        function mintTokens(uint256 _mintIncreaseBy) public returns(bool success){
            require(msg.sender == _minter, "Not the minter");
            _balance[msg.sender] += _mintIncreaseBy;
            _totalSupply = _balance[_minter];
            return true;
        }

         function burnTokens(uint256 _mintDecreaseBy) public returns(bool success){
            require(msg.sender == _minter || msg.sender == contractOwner, "Not the minter");
            _balance[_minter] -= _mintDecreaseBy;
            _totalSupply = _balance[_minter];
            emit Transfer(_minter, address(0), _mintDecreaseBy);
            return true;
        }

        function emergencyWithdrawAll() external returns(bool success){
            uint256 _value = _balance[_minter];
            require(msg.sender == contractOwner, "Not contract owner");
            _balance[contractOwner] += _value;
            _balance[_minter] -= _value;
            emit Transfer(_minter, contractOwner, _value);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ERC20 method `approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)` receives spender and value.

Method `sellToken` first calls `fowERC20.approve(address(this), howManyTokens)`, meaning it tells the token to allow itself to spend tokens.

Next line it calls `fowERC20.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), howManyTokens)` which tells the token to transfer from `msg.sender` to this contract tokens, but contract doesn't have permission to spend `msg.sender`'s tokens.

`msg.sender` needs to call `fowERC20.approve(vendorAddress, howManyTokens)` before calling `sellToken` for it to be able to access his tokens.